# Is Worldpay craft plugin integrates Cybersource

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft4, worldpay

I'm kinda new to payment gateways,
Is the craft commerce-worldpay plugin
https://plugins.craftcms.com/commerce-worldpay

integrates Cybersource as stated in this worldpay docs
https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/worldpay-business-payments?

and is Worldpay gateway is different from Cybersource?
https://www.cybersource.com/en-us/solutions/payment-acceptance/payment-gateway.html